# Register Google Tag Manager into bogy tag

Tags: google-tag-manager

I have an ASP.net application. I need to register Google tag manager on the pages but this operation should be done in userControl because I need GTM only on pages where this userControl is present.
The issue is that GTM script should be after opening Body tag. If I do ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock in inserts GTM after Form tag. How can I insert GTM script from user control after Body tag?

Answer (score 0):

A possible answer for your problem is implenting GTM in every page just after the body tag but set up the events (or rules, depending on the version you use) so the scripts you will run will be triggered specifically on the pages you want.